# Ionic | how to give ID for each device

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to find a way to give any id or something for each phone so i can use the database information under this id.

For example:
Device #45875 made a change. 
\
Find in db id 45875 and change firstname to Bob.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get id for a phone you can use UUID from the device plugin which
   will give you a Universally Unique Identifier, you can check the
   plugin details [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/). The details of how a UUID is generated are
   determined by the device manufacturer and are specific to the
   device's platform or model.
2. Also you can use the [Unique Device ID](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/) plugin this one will
   remain the same even if the user uninstall the app, This plugin
   requires sim permissions. The id is generated by a combination of
   the following:

   - Secure.ANDROID_ID: according to the android docs, this is stable over    the whole livetime of a device
   - TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(): should be stable
   - TelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber): depends on the SIM currently       plugged to the device --> unstable
3. You can also use the [sim plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/) to get the deviceId for
   example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones, you
   will also need to have sim permissions to use it. It won't work on
   devices without a sim card.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) on first install and save it locally (e.g. using Ionic Storage). You can then send this identifier to your backend and create a "device" with this ID. You then use it in all communication between your app and the backend.

If you users log in to any account, like Facebook, Twitter, etc, connect this to the "device id". This way you can also have multiple devices connected to the same accounts etc.